# Strange rendering using SlimDX (holes in faces)

Tags: c#, directx, slimdx, directx-11

I have a problem just with rendering a simple rotating cube with SlimDX (DirectX 11). Cube is rotating and these are the images i get:

[image: Problem with the rendering]

I use this vertex shader:

```
    float4x4 WorldViewProj : register(c0);
    float4 VShader(float4 position : POSITION) : SV_POSITION
    {
        return mul(float4(position.xyz, 1.0), WorldViewProj);
    }
```

And this is how i prepare WorldViewProj:

```
ProjectionMatrix = Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH((float)(Math.PI / 4.0), 1f, -1, 20);
ViewMatrix = Matrix.LookAtLH(new Vector3(0f, 0, ypos), new Vector3(0f, 0, 10), new Vector3(0f, 1f, 0f)); 

Matrix positionMatrix = Matrix.Translation(position);
Matrix rotationMatrix = Matrix.RotationYawPitchRoll(rotation.X, rotation.Y, rotation.Z);
Matrix scaleMatrix = Matrix.Scaling(scale);
Matrix worldMatrix = rotationMatrix * scaleMatrix * positionMatrix;
worldMatrix = Matrix.Transpose(worldMatrix);

Matrix WorldViewProj = ViewMatrix * ProjectionMatrix * worldMatrix;
```

First of all i saw this question: [Incorrect Clipping and 3D Projection when using SlimDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739442/incorrect-clipping-and-3d-projection-when-using-slimdx)

And, probably, there's something wrong with matrices (since i don't transpose neither view nor projection but transpose world - in opposite case nothing is rendered). But even if i set both view and projection matrices to identity matrix the "hole" is still there.

Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure offhand, but aren't you specifying -1 in Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH() for the near plane? If yes, why aren't you setting a positive value?

Comment: Wild wild guess: z-buffer resolution is too small?

Comment: Even if i do (0.0001f or 1f) - the picture is exactly the same.

Comment: Resolution? Well, i create buffer using `new Texture2D()` and its size is exactly matches the size of the RenderForm. And format is `Format.D32_Float`

Comment: The problem is found. It was just a wrong order of vertices in an index buffer. Shame on me:) Thanks everybody for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is found. It was just a wrong order of vertices in an index buffer. Shame on me:) Thanks everybody for your help!